# Add a select option if not found and have it as selected + jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update all the selectboxes in a table with a value from another select box . For example if the outside select box has the value Greewich Media and user clicks the button, then all the selectboxes in the table should have Greenwich media as selected. If there is no Greenwhich media in the selectbox inside the table then new option should be added and be selected.

```
<select class="acc" id="accList" style="width:148px">
    <option value="000000000000000001">Greenwich Media</option>
    <option value="000000000000000002">Greenwich Media1</option>
</select>
<input id="assignAccounts" class="btn assignAccounts" type="submit" value="Assign this account to All Rows">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="accSelectandlookup" id="someList0" style="width:148px">
                <option value="000000000000000001">Greenwich Media</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="accSelectandlookup" id="someList1" style="width:148px">
                <option value="000000000000000002">Greenwich Media1</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('.assignAccounts').click(function () {
    $('.accSelectandlookup').each(function (i, obj) {
        // How do i assign add new option if it does not exist and keep it selected, 
        // if exists then keep that selected
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can read a selected value and option object in `accList`, then by iterating all `accSelectandlookup` you can check if option is available or not. If not available then add option and set value.

```
$('.assignAccounts').click(function () {
    var selectedVal = $('#accList').val();
    var selectedOption = $('#accList option[value="'+selectedVal+'"]');

    $('.accSelectandlookup').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('option[value="'+selectedVal+'"]').length <= 0)
        {
          $(this).append($(selectedOption).clone());
        }
         $(this).val(selectedVal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below uses Greenwich Media option `value="000000000000000001"` to find relevant options.

```js
$('.assignAccounts').click(function () {

    //check if GreenwichMedia is selected
    var greenwichMediaSelected = ($('#accList').val() === "000000000000000001") ? true : false;

    if (greenwichMediaSelected) {
        
        $('.accSelectandlookup').each(function (i, obj) {
            var hasGreenwichMedia = $(this).find('[value="000000000000000001"]').length;
            if (!hasGreenwichMedia) {
                $(this).append('<option value="000000000000000001">Greenwich Media</option>');
            }                  
        });
        
        //set GreenwichMedia option selected
        $('.accSelectandlookup').val( "000000000000000001" );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="acc" id="accList" style="width:148px">
    <option value="000000000000000001">Greenwich Media</option>
    <option value="000000000000000002">Greenwich Media1</option>
</select>
<input id="assignAccounts" class="btn assignAccounts" type="submit" value="Assign this account to All Rows">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="accSelectandlookup" id="someList0" style="width:148px">
                <option value="000000000000000001">Greenwich Media</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="accSelectandlookup" id="someList1" style="width:148px">
                <option value="000000000000000002">Greenwich Media1</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="accSelectandlookup" id="someList2" style="width:148px">
                 <option value="0000000000000000010">BBC Media</option>
                <option value="000000000000000001">Greenwich Media</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```